# Удаленная работа Raspberry Pi 3 с MacBook

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Все привет. Приобрел *Raspberry Pi 3*. На данный момент подключаюсь удаленно с MacBook Air по ssh 
и VNC, но скорость последнего оставляет желать лучшего. Да и IDE для python на малинке не ахти. Я привык к **Visual Studio Code** или **Atom**, и мне интересно:

Могу ли я настроить работу так, чтобы подключатся к малинке по тому же ssh, держать проект на малинке, а открывать и редактировать файлы на macbookе?

Answer (score 0):

Да, конечно.
Для того же Atom'а куча плагинов:

- https://atom.io/packages/sftp-deployment
- https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp

(подойдет всё что относится к sftp)